# How to get rid of componentWillMount yellow warning banners in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

Currently my app is getting a lot of yellow banner warnings for component will mount, however I am unable to get rid of them as they are in third party libraries.  Is there a way I can make them not come up as they are disruptive for development?

Comment: You can disable it by following `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#warnings`

Comment: Thanks that worked!
#ReadTheDocs!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've been able to do it with the `YellowBox` module.

I'm using an Expo managed project v38 that uses React Native v0.62.

Example:

```
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  "componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use."
]);
```

For later versions the `LogBox` module must be used: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/07/06/version-0.63